# How to make a getter or regular method waits until AsyncTask Complete its work?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to do a bunch of code in background thread for me to prevent UI frozen. The AsyncTask result is OK and I can use that result in onPostExecute.
But the problem is that outside AsyncTask after initializing and executing the asyncTask i cannot access the result because it's on background thread.
for Example

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

MyObject mObject = new Myobject(getApplicationContext());
mObject.getStart();
mObject.getResult();

}
```

---

```
    public class MyObject extends Parent{

    Context context;

    public MyObject (Context context, long startTimeStamp) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        setStart(startTimeStamp);

            MyAsyncTask async = new MyAsyncTask ();
            async.execute("");

     }

    private Object myTestMethod() {

       if(true)
        return true;

       return false;
     }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... strings) {

            return myTestMethod();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            setResult(o);
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
public class Parent{

private long start;
private Object result;


public long getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(long start) {
    this.start = start;
}

public Object getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Object result) {
    this.result = result;
}
}
```

---

In the first class when I call `getStart()` from super class it return **StartTime** and works **good**, but when i Call `getResult()` it returns **null** because AsyncTask is working in **background**, I search and found this But

```
    try {
        MyAsyncTask async = new MyAsyncTask ();
        setResult(async.execute().get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**It will wait and frozen the Foreground**.

If there is any solution for my setter method to wait until AsyncTask Complete the task and then return the result
or any other suggestion
I am glad to hear

If Example was unClear comment me to make you clear

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't this defeat the purpose of an asyncTask? The purpose of an async task is to defer the processing work onto a background thread and then asynchronously make a callback to the main thread with the result.

```
MyObject mObject = new Myobject(getApplicationContext());
mObject.getStart();
mObject.getResult();
```

By doing the above its already synchronous. And i do not think it is wise to embedd an aynctask into an object constructor. What i suggest is to run the async task outside of the object and pass the object as a param into post execute with the object fields populated.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
     o.getResult() //this is executed on the main thread
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
but I already knew this and i tried.

So my question was is there any way for my `getResult()` to say: Stop until Background process done it's work, like multithreading?
if not what do you suggest wich when i call my `getResult()` i should not be null!

Comment: the only thing i can think of is a simple null check.